# Count and sum all previous like terms

Tags: python, list, loops, count, sum

Suppose we have a list of terms:

`termList = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "E"]`

---

Now, suppose we have another list, containing more lists:

`otherList = [["A, "E"], ["A", "B", "C", "C"], ["B", "B"], ["A", "C"]]`

---

What I would like to do is for each index of `otherList`, check the sum of each of its terms plus those of all previous indices to see that the total amount of each term has not exceeded that in `termList`.

For example:

- Iteration 1: A (1), E (1)
- Iteration 2: A (2), B (1), C (2), E (1)
- Iteration 3: Finds that there are three instances of B. This is more than the one instance that is present in `termList` so the loop ends.

---

I am stuck on how to do this without nesting a million loops. I'm thinking we can use a combination of a generator expression, `all`, and `sum` but can't quite figure out how to add all the previous terms and also check that all sums are valid.

Comment: I see here only 3 loops - to count termlist element, to get otherList element( sublist), to count sublist elements (and add result to global sum). maybe with "collections.Counter()" it could be one loop.

Comment: Basically you wst to have the count of each value in a flat andca nested list and compate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Counter`s would work for you and you can add them together:

```
from collections import Counter
termList = ["A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "E"]
otherList = [["A", "E"], ["A", "B", "C", "C"], ["B", "B"], ["A", "C"]]

term_count = Counter(termList)
c = Counter()
for lst in otherList:
    c += Counter(lst)
    if any(c[v] > term_count[v] for v in c):
        break
    print(c)
else:
    print('Exhausted')
```

Output:

```
Counter({'A': 1, 'E': 1})
Counter({'C': 2, 'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'E': 1})
```

Comment: Ah, I think this is what I was looking for. Is your output correct or would the third line actually read "Exhausted"?

Comment: The `else` clause of a for loop only executes if the loop doesn't `break`, so `Exhausted` would only print if it gets to the end of `otherList`. Moved the `print(c)` after the condition so only outputs required details.

Comment: I read it quickly, sorry. I meant to ask if it should break instead but then saw you had your print statement before the check. The edit is better; thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this homework?  One way to do this would involve two dictionaries.  Iterate over the first list and increment the dictionary value by 1 for each instance.  Output for your example would be:  `{ 'A' : 2, 'B' : 1, 'C': 3, 'E' : 1 }`.  Next iterate over each list inside other list and do the same thing with a separate dictionary.  Output would be:  `{ 'A' : 3, 'E' : 1, 'B' : 3, 'C' : 3 }`

Now compare your lists (or do it while you iterate over the second list).  You'll probably also want to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) for your dictionaries to return 0 as the default value.  This saves you the annoyance of having to account for key errors.

Also it's not exactly clear what you mean by previous in this sentence.

> check the sum of each of its terms plus those of all **previous** indices to see that the total amount of each term has not exceeded that in `termList`.